# How to launch new view with the clicked argument?

Tags: android

I am new to android development - what I am not familiar with is how to send the user to a new view and include an argument (such as an item object) along with it. I would like to teach myself but I'm not quite sure what I am looking for. I think I need to send an intent to create a new view. In the overloaded "onItemClick" function you can see comments specifying exactly where I need to add code - this is the part I am not sure how to proceed on. Thanks for all help!

```
public class RoomActivity extends Activity {

GlobalClass globalClass;

TextView roomName;
TextView roomDescription;
Room thisRoom;

Button north;
Button south;
Button east;
Button west;

// this list view holds the options available in the room, each option is clickable and should
// bring up it's own subview
ListView listy;

// adaptor used to bind a string array of options to the list view
ArrayAdapter la;

/**
 * Populates the main list view with the contents of list
 * @param list an array of strings that are put into the list view
 */
public void populateList (int listID, ArrayList<String> list){
    listy = (ListView) findViewById(listID);
    la = new ArrayAdapter(this.getBaseContext(), R.layout.list_item, R.id.list_item_text, list.toArray());
    listy.setAdapter(la);
    listy.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position,
                                long arg3)
        {
            String value = (String)adapter.getItemAtPosition(position);
            Item item = thisRoom.getItem(position);
            // Verified that the item object is correctly populated.
            // Send "item" as argument to the "activity_item" layout
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_room);

    globalClass = (GlobalClass) getApplicationContext();
    if(thisRoom == null)
        thisRoom = globalClass.getRoom(1);
    roomName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.room_name);
    roomDescription = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.room_description);

    north = (Button) findViewById(R.id.north_button);
    south = (Button) findViewById(R.id.south_button);
    east = (Button) findViewById(R.id.east_button);
    west = (Button) findViewById(R.id.west_button);

    setRoomView();
}

public void setRoomView () {
    roomName.setText(thisRoom.getName());
    roomDescription.setText(thisRoom.getDescription());
    populateList(R.id.character_list, globalClass.getCharacterNames((thisRoom.getCharacters())));
    populateList(R.id.item_list, globalClass.getItemNames(thisRoom.getItems()));
}

public void onClickMove (View view) {
    Button button = (Button) view;
    switch (button.getId()){
        case (R.id.north_button):
            if (thisRoom.northRoomId != 0){
                thisRoom = globalClass.getRoom(thisRoom.northRoomId);
                setRoomView();
            }
            break;

        case (R.id.south_button):
            if (thisRoom.southRoomId != 0){
                thisRoom = globalClass.getRoom(thisRoom.southRoomId);
                setRoomView();
            }
            break;

        case (R.id.east_button):
            if (thisRoom.eastRoomId != 0){
                thisRoom = globalClass.getRoom(thisRoom.eastRoomId);
                setRoomView();
            }
            break;

        case (R.id.west_button):
            if (thisRoom.westRoomId != 0){
                thisRoom = globalClass.getRoom(thisRoom.westRoomId);
                setRoomView();
            }
            break;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: do you want to add a button, when clicked you start another Activity (view) passing it some arguments?

Comment: There is already an onItemClickListener on each listview item so I want it to launch a new view and include the item you clicked on as part of the intent.

Answer (score 1):

at your onItemClick()

```
Intent intent = new Intent(RoomActivity.this, ItemActivity.class);
String extra = "YOUR PASSED DATA";
intent.putExtra(EXTRA, extra);
startActivty();
```

at the RoomActivity class

```
public static final String EXTRA = "MY_EXTRA";
```

at ItemActivity.onCreate()

String item = getIntent().getStringExtra(RoomActivity.EXTRA);

I don't know if the Item class is Serializable or not, but in case it not: use [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/%E2%80%8E) library to serialize/deserialize your Item object. It's easy to use; just read their guide.

At any case, I don't recommend this way of serializing and deserializing, you may extract the important fields (indeed primitives) from your Item at the RoomActivity and pass them using the Intent; and in the ItemActivity, just re-construct the Item.

Answer (score 0):

Add this where you want to pass your data:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("MyData1", obj);
```

Add this where you want to retrieve you data:

```
getIntent().getSerializableExtra("MyData1");
```

Anyway, there's a good explanation on the official page on Android Developers here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Answer (score 0):

So here you go starting new Activity (view):

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, AnotherViewActivity.class);
i.putExtra("ExampleString", "Hello")
startActivity(i);
```

Getting sent data in the activity:

```
String data = getIntent().getExtras().getString("ExampleString");
```